# Debugging Help for Complex Javascript/Typescript Program

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a newbie to Javascript and Typescript and I am trying to get a better understanding of how one particular large, existing application executes step by step. Any recommendations for a debugger or similar tool?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This kind of question is not suitable for Stackoverflow unfortunately, sorry. Browsers have built in debuggers. Not sure about other browsers, but Chrome has a decent one.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Chrome Dev tools. In the source tab you can set breakpoints. Mostly values will be checked through console.log. For nodejs applications there is a debugger you can check more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/). WebStorm integrated it quite nicely.